# How to implement ClickOnce Update Strategy to update only files changed between versions?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2013, clickonce

I deploying my Windows Forms project using ClickOnce in Visual Studio 2013, when the users perform an update of the new version, all files of the system is downloaded every time a new version is available on the server.

I need realize a configuration when the client upgraded the system only download the files modified between versions.

I see [Choosing a ClickOnce Update Strategy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s22azw1e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) article on describe the configuration of the updates into ClickOnce but in nowhere I seen what I need.

Any help is really useful, Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ClickOnce automatically uses file patching to avoid redundant downloading of application files. It compares the hash signatures of the files specified in the application manifest for the current application against the signatures in the manifest for the new version.
File patching does not work for files that are marked as data and stored in the data directory. These are always downloaded regardless of the file's hash signature. Files are marked as data files in your ClickOnce application's application manifest file.

If you use Visual Studio to compile your application, it will generate new hash signatures for all files whenever you rebuild the entire project. In this case, all assemblies will be downloaded to the client, although only a few assemblies may have changed.

Copy the specific files to the ClickOnce folder. Edit the .manifest and .application files with MageUI. Increment the version number in both those files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I solved my problem applying manually the files into new version.